# Next.js Import image error Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

i was started learning about styled components and next.js. I want import image to my background but i have problem with import. I watched a few tutorial and people dont have this problem where they projects looks like mine. i want import image like that

```
import front from "../img/front.jpeg"
```

I want try use this import file in my background-image

```
    const HomeTop = styled.div`
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url('${front}');`
```

and also i tried include this import to IMG

```
 <img src={front} alt="" />
```

but in both way i have the same error

[image: error]

They are  basic things and i lost too much time to find resolve. What is wrong?

Comment: I'm willing to bet it's because it is .jpeg and not ,jpg.

Comment: i tried with different img with jpg, same error.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I was having problems with:

`import logo from "@company/shared-library/media/logo.png"`

all I had to do was:

1. install the npm package `next-images`
2. Create a `next.config.js` at the root of your project
3. Edit `next.config.js` so it looks like:

```js
const withImages = require('next-images')

module.exports = {
    ...withImages(),
    future: {
        webpack5: true,
    },

}
```

Comment: Still not working... `error - ./assets/img/sidebar-2.jpg
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)`

Answer (score 2):

WHAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAT i restart VISUAL Studio Code and localhost and now its working. Arghhh i lost few hours!!!! haha thanks.

Turn off and on  ist the best rule

Answer (score 2):

First, install `url-loader`

```
$ yarn add url-loader --dev
```

Next, create a  [next.config.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-webpack-config) at the root of your folder to extend `webpack` config  like so:

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    config.module.rules.push(
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?[a-z0-9=.]+)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' 
      }
    )
    return config
  },
}
```

Last, import your file and use it at your `styled-components` , and don't forget to restart your dev server.

```
import front from "../img/front.jpeg"

...

const HomeTop = styled.div`
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(${front});
`;
```

Note: to use `styled-components` we need `.babelrc` at our root project as well

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": [["styled-components", { "ssr": true }]]
}
```

Comment: Still not working... `error - ./assets/img/sidebar-2.jpg
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)`

Answer (score 1):

Since you are importing a real image you canuse the template literals 
Do this to set the url :

On ES5 :

```
backgroundImage: "url(" + front + ")"
```

On ES6 -

```
backgroundImage: `url(${front})`
```

or

```
backgroundImage: `url("${front}")`
```

Comment: all funcion is in template string, its styled component. Template started after styled.div and end after  background-image: url('${front}');

Comment: this same error is without code, even without style and <img/>

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar problem and the cause appears to be that webpack doesn't know how to process your images and you need to tell it that those should be treated as resources.

So in the webpack.rules.js you need to add:

```
  {
    test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
    type: 'asset/resource',
  },
```

Comment: Note that this appears to only work for Webpack v5+, not v4: https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/